# Horizontal Smooth Scroll Navbar with Div Anchor Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a sticky horizontal scrolling navbar with dates 1800, 1801, 1802, etc. for a timeline.

As I scroll down I want the dates to scroll horizontally within the navbar correlating with the div that I am currently on.

The dates should also act as links in the navbar and smooth scroll vertically to the corresponding div.

I can't seem to get the navbar to scroll horizontally, as the dates just run off the webpage when I added `overflow:hidden`

This is all I have so far:

```
 <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#dag1">1839</a>
        <a href="#">1840</a>
        <a href="#">1841</a>
        <a href="#">1842</a>
        <a href="#">1843</a>
        <a href="#">1844</a>
        <a href="#">1845</a>
        <a href="#">1846</a>
        <a href="#">1847</a>
        <a href="#">1848</a>
        <a href="#">1849</a>
        <a href="#fact1">1861</a>
        <a href="#brownie1">1900</a>
        <a href="#polaroid1">1948</a>
        <a href="#konica1">1978</a>
        <a href="#kodak1">1991</a>
        <a href="#canon1">2005</a>
```

and the CSS:

```
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100%;
    height:75;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

An example can be seen here: https://duffy.com/30-years/

Comment: The link is broken. PAGE NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

If it's a sticky navigation you want there it is.

```
ul {
 position:fixed; /* sticky part */
 width:33%;
}

li {
 float:left;
 margin-left:1%;
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:4%;
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:#999;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Unkn0wn96/pen/xRJPgp